# how to crop an image from detected edges in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have breast mri images and my purpose is to crop original images from edges that detected with fuzzy filtering method. in other words i want to have just breast not area around it.

Comment: Explain your question with an example. This (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may help you to ask a question to receive a good answer.

Comment: Without much more details probably noone can answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

[original breast image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9c2u.png)

for example at above picture green edges was detected. second picture is my goal:
 [my question is about this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFIr8.png)